# Error with Case.SourceId field in a record edit form component in Spring '20 - works fine in Winter '20

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a Lightning record edit form base component with the following simple markup:

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-p-around--small"> 
<lightning:inputField fieldName="SourceId" value="{!v.caseRecord.SourceId}"/> 
</div>
```

**This component works fine in Winter '20 sandboxes** but it doesn't work in Spring '20 sandboxes (a Lightning error appears on the page once the component tries to load and the issue is falling on the Case.SourceId field).

In Spring'20, the error is making reference to a null pointer. However, there is definitely a value in the SourceId field of the caseRecord. The SourceId field is being populated as a result of email-to-case On Demand flow.

I know that it is the SourceId field that is the culprit because I removed all other fields in the component one by one and refreshed the browser each time and it only fails when SourceId is in that component.

There seems to be no documentation from Salesforce on this - it seems very strange to me.

I have raised a case with Salesforce Support but haven't received a response yet.